# Why windows defender consumes a lot of my computer's memory?

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager, windows-defender

My PC is running slow because of Windows Defender's Anti-Malware Service.
What should I do?
I have already disabled REAL TIME protection.

[image: win taskmanager SS]

Comment: Perhaps you can run the definition updates and complete at least 1 smart scan so it can use less resources when done? I think there is also an option where you cam set the CPU usage to like 10% max.

Comment: 92MB is all your memory or do you mean the reason it's writting data to your disk drive?

Comment: Yes I meant as you said. Finnally I turned off it on administrator setting.

Comment: defender is known to slow down windows. use a free 3rd party tool like Avast